# Does exploit development have a future?

Tags: exploit, reverse-engineering

Does exploit development have a future?

I mean there are a lot of fuzzers and they can find bugs better and with less time than humans.

And today's there are lots of great fuzzers.

I love exploit development, but is it worth it to learn exploit development today or not?

Comment: Fuzzers exist to help, not to do the work for you, and also they do not always succeed.

Answer (score 1):

yes definitely, fuzzer just helps you to find a potentially vulnerable code. It can be a coding error but not a security issue. Fuzzing is also difficult, you need to come up with good seed test cases and then you can use tools like AFL to mutate them.

Once a crash is found, you can look into it and see if it is a security issue. And then you will go into a whole different domain - exploit development.

Operating System has a lot of protection mechanism by default nowadays and it makes exploit development much harder than before.

Exploit development is turning a bug into an arbitrary code execution and allows the attacker to hijack the privilege of the running process.

Answer (score 1):

Is it worth it to learn exploit development today or not?

[image: Prices for 0-days by 0-ethics company.]

Comment: This doesn't _explicitly_ answer whether it has a future, just whether it is a thing in the present. However given the price range (even if it is largely PR marketing), it is certainly safe to say that it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is Yes. In fact you have this company https://zerodium.com/ that makes a lot of money by buying/creating/developing exploits.